# Matlab @fmincon error: "Supplied objective function must return a scalar value"

Tags: matlab

EDIT: To help clarify my question, I'm looking to get a fit to the following data:

[image]

I can get a fit using the cftool function, but using a least squares approach doesn't make sense with my binary data. Just to illustrate...

[image]

So, my goal is to fit this data using the fmincon function.

ORIGINAL POST:

I have data from a movement control experiment in which participants were timed while they performed a task, and given a score (failure or success) based on their performance. As you might expect, we assume participants will make less errors as they have more time to perform the task.

I'm trying to fit a function to this data using fmincon, but get the error "Error using fmincon (line 609)
Supplied objective function must return a scalar value."
I don't understand a) what this means, or b) how I can fix it.

I provide some sample data and code below. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
%Example Data:

time = [12.16 11.81 12.32 11.87 12.37 12.51 12.63 12.09 11.25
7.73 8.18 9.49 10.29 8.88 9.46 10.12 9.76 9.99 10.08
7.48 7.88 7.81 6.7 7.68 8.05 8.23 7.84 8.52 7.7 
6.26 6.12 6.19 6.49 6.25 6.51 6 6.79 5.89 5.93 3.97 4.91 4.78 4.43
3.82 4.72 4.72 4.31 4.81 4.32 3.62 3.71 4.29 3.46 3.9 3.73 4.15
3.92 3.8 3.4 3.7 2.91 2.84 2.7 2.83 2.46 3.19 3.44 2.67 3.49 2.71
3.17 2.97 2.76 2.71 2.88 2.52 2.86 2.83 2.64 2.02 2.37 2.38
2.53 3.03 2.61 2.59 2.59 2.44 2.73 ]

error = [0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1];

%Code:

% initial parameters - a corresponds to params(1), b corresponds to params(2)
a = 3.0;
b = -0.01;

LL = @(params) 1/1+params(1)*(log(time).^params(2));
LL([a b]); 
pOpt = fmincon(LL,[a b],[],[]);
```

Comment: You introduce `error` but you do not use it within your minimisation. Is this on purpose?

Comment: Exactly as the error states, your objective function (`LL`) returns an array, not a scalar value. This is because `time` is an array, so `log(time)` is an array, thus the output of `LL` is an array... You need to take some measure on this array, to convert it to a scalar value - the scalar value to minimize! Commonly, you might take the `norm`, `max`, `mean`, distance measure from some target value...

Comment: This could well be my implementation then. The idea is that the function is:
error = 1/1+a*(log(time).^b);
I thought that LL would correspond to error here, but could well be mistaken.

Comment: You may have forgotten some parenthesis because the 1/1 seems useless...

Comment: -1: Your question is not minimal, and the error message clearly points to the function `LL`; what have you tried to address this error?

Answer (score 1):

The mistakes comes from the function LL, that returns a number of values equal to the length of `time`.

To properly use `fmincon`, you need to have a function that returns only one value.

Comment: Thanks - so if I wanted to fit the model to the data I have here, how would I actually go about doing it? For example, if you plot (time, error), how would you get the best fit to this data using fmincon?

Comment: ok, I have accepted the answer. Thanks for your help here and I look forward to your assistance with the next question!

Comment: actually, reading back over my original question, I did ask how to fix the problem, so I don't think the above is a full answer. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @X__, as I said, to fix the problem, you should rewrite LL (depending on what you need to do with it) so it returns only one value. As it is written now, LL returns an array of N values (N being the length of `time`).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is kind of like the old 'how to draw an owl' thing...
1) draw some circles
2) draw the rest of the f**king owl
That's to say, I understand what you're telling me to do, but I have no idea how to implement it. So it is an answer in the strictest form of the word, but it doesn't help advance anything.

Comment: @X__, remember you changed the body of your question (to add another question) *after* I answered it. Then since no one can read your mind and know what you want to do with the function `LL`, that currently have several outputs, the only thing we can say is to reduce it's outputs to one instead of "a lot".

Comment: @X__ the edit seems to be a different question, that's why I'm confused. Anyway, have a nice day. Good luck.

Comment: note that I made my edits after I read a comment you posted previously but deleted, which may have added to the confusion here. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Lessons learnt all round: don't *ask* broad/unclear questions, and don't *answer* broad/unclear questions until they are clarified in the comments. This answer is a more brief version of a comment I'd already posted for instance.

Comment: @X__, my comment didn't ask you to change the body of the question, but to ask a new one once this one is finished because you were asking question in the comments which is not a good practice in SO.

Comment: @Wolfie, you can see that there are only a few seconds between your comment and my answer. And the question was pretty clear to me *before it gets edited*. But I understand what you say and you are probably right.

Comment: @Bebs True, but see my comment above re the owl thing. Also, why did you delete your previous comment? Either way, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @X__, yeah I explained how to draw an owl, but at the end you decided you want to draw an owl in a specific position standing on a specific tree with a specific lighting according to a specific sun set... Never mind I hope someone will understand your question. I did my best here. And I delete the previous comments because it's not a good practice to have much comments so I will remove all these ones soon. We can still discuss in the chat but I think I haven't much more to say here. Regards.

Comment: @Bebs, Ok, I think the owl thing hasn't been understood as intended but thanks all the same for your efforts here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe logistic regression would fit your data and purposes nicely. In that case, why not simply use Matlab's built-in function for multinomial logistic regression?

```
B = mnrfit(time,error)
```

Regarding your function `LL`, are you sure you have entered the function correctly and are not missing a parentheses?

```
LL = @(params) 1/(1+params(1)*(log(time).^params(2)));
```

Without the parentheses, you function is equivalent to 1 + a*log(x)^b